# Haskell type signature in lambda expression

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a lambda expression in my program like:

```
\x -> f $ x + 1
```

and I want to specify for type safety that x must be an Integer. Something like:

```
-- WARNING: bad code
\x::Int -> f $ x + 1
```

Comment: (\x -> f $ (x::Int) + 1)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "for type safety"? In what way would the inferred type for `x` (`Num a => a`) be less safe than `Int`?

Comment: @sepp2k The actual code I'm writing does show x, and a lot of things can be shown, but I only want this lambda to compile if x is of a certain type, like Int. The code in the question is not the actual code, it's just the shortest way to ask the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just write `\x -> f $ (x::Int) + 1` instead. Or, perhaps more readable, `\x -> f (x + 1 :: Int)`. Note that type signatures generally encompass everything to their left, as far left as makes syntactic sense, which is the opposite of lambdas extending to the right.

The GHC extension `ScopedTypeVariables` incidentally allows writing signatures directly in patterns, which would allow `\(x::Int) -> f $ x + 1`. But that extension also adds a bunch of other stuff you might not want to worry about; I wouldn't turn it on just for a syntactic nicety.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I'm actually using this in Template Haskell, and just FYI regarding the second option, GHC 7.4.1 says "Type signatures in patterns not (yet) handled by Template Haskell".

Comment: Haha, yeah. TH doesn't understand quite a few syntactic extensions that GHC supports, alas.

Answer (score 13):

I want to add to C.A.McCann's answer by noting that you don't need  `ScopedTypeVariables`.  Even if you never use the variable, you can always still do:

```
\x -> let _ = (x :: T) in someExpressionThatDoesNotUseX
```